# Combine an HTML attribute onClick function with a jQuery On function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

There's a site I'm working on with legacy onclick functions on input elements:

```
<input name="input_41" type="radio" value="76" id="choice_41_1" onclick="gf_apply_rules(5,[6,7,8]);">
```

Unfortunately, I can't change or modify the legacy code directly.

I'm also trying to update the site and make the form elements prettier with additional CSS and JS. One of the new functions I'm using to handle radio elements uses the jQuery `On()` function. This function works well but appears to override the existing onclick function `gf_apply_rules()`. Here is an example of the jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click.radio.data-api', '[data-toggle^=radio], .radio', function (e) {
    var $radio = $(e.target);
    e && e.preventDefault() && e.stopPropagation();
    if (!$radio.hasClass('radio')) $radio = $radio.closest('.radio');
    $radio.find(':radio').radio('toggle');
});
```

Is there anyway I can keep the existing HTML specified onclick function firing with `On()`?

Comment: I know that you can do multiple functions per onclick. You would format it like this `onclick="css(),On()"`, though I've never personally tried a CSS change and a jQuery function at the same time.

Comment: Ah, I should have mentioned that I need to avoid changing the legacy code.

Comment: Oh I see. So you want the HTML to be left unchanged, but want to also call the jQuery function onclick?

Comment: You're using `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`, which will probably stop the onclick from firing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The e.preventDefault() will prevent the original (older) onclick handler. Did you try removing that line to see if both event handlers get called. . . ?

Comment: That's it. No need to combine, commenting out `e.preventDefault()` as you suggest solves it and preserves my legacy code.

Comment: Great. I'll take some points for 'accepted answer' so that I can eventually lose them the next time I hate on Internet Explorer CSS rendering issues in the future on Stackoverflow :)